# Custom form template, issue with field marked as "append changes to existing text"

Tags: versioning, list-form, template

I've created a custom form template for a content type. The content type is used in a list with versioning enabled and contains a field marked as "append changes to existing text".

In the template I'm using my custom form followed by the default list iterator:

```
<ProzesseForm:AddForm runat="server" />
<SharePoint:ListFieldIterator ID="ListFieldIterator1" runat="server"/>
```

As my form control contains all fields of the list definition, the list field iterator normally doesn't display anything. The only issue exists in the display mode of the form. In this mode the iterator displays the versioned fields of my column marked as "append changes to existing text" below my form.

I've tried to add the control SharePoint:AppendOnlyHistory to my form, which will display the same as the list iterator, still the iterator will show the versioned values.

```
 <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="FormField18" FieldName="AktuelleBewertung" />
 <SharePoint:AppendOnlyHistory runat="server" FieldName="AktuelleBewertung" ControlMode="Display" />
```

Which control do I have to add in order to skip the rendering of the list field operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added the field to the ExcludeFields property of the list field iterator.

```
<SharePoint:ListFieldIterator ID="ListFieldIterator1" runat="server" ExcludeFields="AktuelleBewertung" />
```